# How can I add a link to a CKEditor5 label

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am creating a form with this code:

```
export class GlossCke5FormView extends View {
  constructor(locale) {
    super(locale);

    this.focusTracker = new FocusTracker();
    this.keystrokes = new KeystrokeHandler();

    this.numericInputView = this._createInput('Glossary Term Numeric ID ');
    ...
```

With the _createInput function defined here:

```
_createInput( label ) {
    const labeledInput = new LabeledFieldView( this.locale, createLabeledInputText );

    labeledInput.label = label;

    return labeledInput;
}
```

I tried adding `<a href="/gloss">link</a>` to the end but no luck. It just ends up being rendered as plain text.

How can I add a link the the end of the label?